# Show latest 5 post only on homepage in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have created a function to show latest 5 posts only on home page. But it is also shown on page 2.

My code is:

```
function wp_latest_pst()
    {
        $the_query = new WP_Query( array
        ( 
        'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ), 
        'posts_per_page' => 5
        ) );

        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
            $p_count=$the_query->post_count;
            switch ($p_count)
            {
                case '1':
                $content = '<div class="featured-1 featured clearfix">';
                break;
                case '2':
                $content = '<div class="featured-2 featured clearfix">';
                break;
                case '3':
                $content = '<div class="featured-3 featured clearfix">';
                break;
                case '4':
                $content = '<div class="featured-4 featured clearfix">';
                break;
                case '5':
                $content = '<div class="featured-5 featured clearfix">';
                break;   
}           
                echo $content;

            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/featured', get_post_format() );

            endwhile;
            ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
```

I am using this function on index.php as:

```
        <?php
        if ( is_home() || is_front_page() ):
        wp_latest_pst();
        endif;
        ?>
```

I do not want to use CSS to hide this on next pages.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean it's shown on page 2? What theme are you using by the way?

Comment: page 2 means when we navigate the website: 

http://example.com  -> home page
http://example.com/page/2

I am creating theme myself.

Comment: I was going to edit your code but I'll just comment instead, here we're going to use the is_paged() function provided by wordpress. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_paged If you can't figure it out, let me know.

Comment: thank you very much. It is working now as I want.

Comment: Glad you got it working, have a nice one.